# Prestashop 1.7 Descuentos Pedido vía API

Tags: webservice, prestashop

buenas..

En la API de prestashop 1.6 hay un servicio web llamado order_discount que en la versión 1.7 ya no está o no lo he sabido ver.

En la base de datos he localizado la tabla, es la llamada ps_order_cart_rule, pero no se como acceder a ella.

Sabeis como puedo recuperar los descuentos aplicados en un pedido usando la API? o de otra manera?

lo necesito para sincronizar un programa ERP con un Prestashop 1.7. Con prestashop 1.6 no tengo ningún problema.

Gracias
:-)

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues lamentablemetne no he encontrado solución para conseguir los descuentos vía API de prestashop.

Así que para salir de paso he atacado directamente a la base de datos del prestashop.

Lo que he hecho ha sido crear los parametros en mi aplicación para conectar con el mysql de prestashop.

Luego hacer un select en la tabla llamada order_cart_rule

string query = String.Format("SELECT id_cart_rule,name,value,value_tax_excl FROM order_cart_rule where id_order={0}",cIdPedido);

y ya tengo lo que quería...

no se si en un futuro volverán a poner el WS de order_discounts pero así he salido del paso y bien.

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he hecho así, ya que a mí el GetByFilter() no me funcionaba.

```
//Cargamos el Factory
Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Factories.OrderCartRuleFactory orderCartRuleFactory = new Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Factories.OrderCartRuleFactory(BaseUrl, Account, "");

List<long> descuentos = orderCartRuleFactory.GetIds();

for (int i = 0; i < descuentos.Count; i++) {

    Bukimedia.PrestaSharp.Entities.order_cart_rule descuento = orderCartRuleFactory.Get(descuentos[i]);

    if (descuento.id_order == order.id) {

        Console.WriteLine("El descuento del pedido con ID " + order.id + " es de " + descuento.value + " euros");

     }
}
```